# Snowflake Data Masking 'Date' datatype

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to mask date using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MASKING POLICY date_mask_ldm AS (val date) RETURNS date ->
CASE
    WHEN IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION('mask_policy_allowed_ldm') THEN val
    ELSE regexp_replace(val,'.+\@', '####')
END;
```

I cannot find anything anywhere online which helps me with this...can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the expected output but if the column is DATE, then you need to return a valid DATE. So maybe you can truncate the dates up to the years.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MASKING POLICY date_mask_ldm AS (val date) 
RETURNS date -> CASE WHEN IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION('mask_policy_allowed_ldm') 
   THEN val 
ELSE DATE_TRUNC( years, val ) END;
```

So if the date is '2022-05-31', it will be shown as '2022-01-01' because of the masking policy.